# How can I remove the indent created by an unordered list

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list written as such

```
<h1>cardinal directions</h1>
<ul>
    <li>east</li>
    <li>west</li>
    <li>north</li>
    <li>south</li>
</ul>
```

... and it appears indented. My questions is - how using CSS can I remove this indentation? I've tried this, but I think there may be a better way.

```
ul {
    margin-left: -19px;
}
```

Is there a list style property or some such thing in CSS that I should be using instead, perhaps something that is more cross browser compatible?

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the padding on the ul to be padding:0

```
<ul style="padding:0">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I need the keep the bullets, however.

Comment: Setting the padding to 10px will kill the indent and still keep the bullets